# Find string in text file and execute a script depending of the result

Tags: text-processing, scripting, string

I have a file (Data.txt) with something like this:

`A=1234597890 B=192.168.1.1`

sometimes B goes first and sometimes only A or B.

So, If I find:

```
  A,    Print A content and execute A script
  B,     "    B    "     "    "     B   "
 A&B,    "   A&B   "     "    "     A   "
Neither, Print a error message
```

Now the problem is the content in A or B is not the same always!

I don't know which would be the best command to use.

Thank you for your help and for trying to understand my basic English :)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in Perl:

```
$ perl -lne 'if(/A=([^\s]+)/){print "A : $1"; `scriptA.sh`} 
           if(/B=([^\s]+)/){print "B : $1"; `scriptB.sh`}' Data.txt
```

#### Explanation

- `-lne` : remove trailing newlines from each input line and add a newline to each `print` call (`-l`); read the file line by line (`-n`) and run the script given by `-e` on each line.
- `` if(/A=([^\s]+)/){print "A : $1"; `scriptA.sh`} `` : if this line matches `A=` something, print `A : something` (the parentheses mean that the pattern is captured and is now saved as `$1`), then run `scriptA`.
- `` if(/B=([^\s]+)/){print "B : $1"; `scriptB.sh`} `` : as above but for B.

Or, you can just extract the values and parse them:

```
$ grep -Po '[AB]=[^\s]+' Data.txt | 
    while IFS="=" read name val; do 
        echo "$name=$val"; 
        [ "$name" = "A" ] && scriptA.sh || scriptB.sh; 
    done
```

#### Explanation

- `grep -Po '[AB]=[^\s]+' Data.txt` : The `-P` enables [PCREs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl_Compatible_Regular_Expressions), and the `-o` will cause `grep` to print each match on a different line. The `[AB]=[^\s]+` means "match A or B, then `=`, then as many non-whitespace characters as possible. The output of this is the full collection of `A=foo` and `B=bar` from your input file, each on its own line.
- `while IFS="=" read name val` : set the ionput field separator to `=` and read two variables. This means that `$name` will be `A` or `B` and `$value` will be the value associated with them.
- `echo "$name=$val";` : print them, change the format to whatever you like.
- `[ "$name" = "A" ] && scriptA.sh || scriptB.sh;` : if `$name` is `A`, run `scriptA.sh`, else run `scriptB.sh`. 
  Both of the solutions above assume that the scripts you want to call are `scriptA.sh` and `scriptB.sh` and that they are in your $PATH. Edit accordingly.

Comment: I got it, thank you very, very much!!!! You are a genius!

Comment: @M_Mike you're welcome. If this answer solves your issue, please take a minute and click the check mark under the vote count to the left, this will [signify to everyone](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) that your issue's been resolved and is the way that thanks are expressed in the site.

Comment: @terdon I'm not sure for `perl` but in regexp **[^\s]** == **\S**

Comment: @Costas, definitely correct for Perl.  Perl has the most powerful regexes in existence (though [not the most efficient implementation](https://swtch.com/~rsc/regexp/regexp1.html)).

Comment: I'm pretty sure `\S` came from PCREs in the first place anyway.